# luatex print "~" non-breaking space issue

Tags: spacing, luatex

How would I replicate a `~` character by printing from Lua? Please see MWE below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
Hello \luadirect{s = ('First Last'):gsub(' ', '--'); tex.print(s)}.  % works
Hello \luadirect{s = ('First Last'):gsub(' ', '~'); tex.print(s)}.  % fails
Hello \luadirect{s = ('First Last'):gsub(' ', '\~'); tex.print(s)}. % fails

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Why does `~` in the code below produce a new line?

```
   \begin{luacode*}
        token.set_macro('NAME','First~Last','global')
    \end{luacode*}
    \NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it's usually easier to understand the expansion in the luatex primitive `\directlua` than in the `luacode` wrappers:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}



\begin{document}
\showoutput
Hello \directlua{s = ('First Last'):gsub(' ', '--'); tex.print(s)}.  % works

Hello \directlua{s = ('First Last'):gsub(' ', '\string~'); tex.print(s)}.  % fails


\end{document}
```

[image]

[moved edited answer to new question]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please see the edit?

Comment: @likethevegetable hmm OK although adding a completely different question after an answer psoted isn't really playing the game

Comment: Okay, I can add a new one.

Comment: @likethevegetable look now

Comment: moved to new question